# Adding nonce value to @Scripts.Render ASP.Net MVC razor pages with NWebSec

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, content-security-policy, nonce

I am trying to implement Content-Security-Policy with the NWebSec NuGet package

The basic configuration level is working at this moment but trying to add nonce for each script and style in the project.

How to add a nonce to the below tags for inline?

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css/file")
```

For BundleConfig,

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Content/Scripts").Include(
                "~/Content/Scripts/General.js"
                ));
```

I tried with a new class and it's working but with the NWebSec package I going nowhere.
Below is their solution with @Html.CspScriptNonce() directives and this is working.

```
 <script @Html.CspScriptNonce()>document.write("Hello world")</script>
<style @Html.CspStyleNonce()>
   h1 {
          font-size: 10em;
        }
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution I tried was to use `@Styles.RenderFormat` in the following way:

```
@Styles.RenderFormat("<link href=\"{0}\" rel=\"stylesheet\" " + @Html.CspStyleNonce() +"/>","~/Content/css/file")
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `NWebSec` with ASP.Net MCV Bundles, you **can not** apply a Nonce, but luckily you don't need to.

There *might* be something you need to change in your `web.config` though. In the `nwebsec > httpHeaderSecurityModule > securityHttpHeaders > content-Security-Policy` section, make sure that `self="true"` for both `style-src` and `script-src`. `self="true"` is the default, though, so if you don't need those elements for any other declarations, you can omit them.

Here's the `nwebsec` section in my web.config. I'm using both style and script bundles, and have no third-party scripts.

```
  <nwebsec>
    <httpHeaderSecurityModule xmlns="http://nwebsec.com/HttpHeaderSecurityModuleConfig.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="NWebsecConfig/HttpHeaderSecurityModuleConfig.xsd">
      <securityHttpHeaders>
        <content-Security-Policy enabled="true">
          <default-src self="true" />
          <font-src self="true">
            <add source="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
          </font-src>
          <object-src none="true" />
          <style-src self="true">
            <add source="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
          </style-src>
          <base-uri none="true" />
        </content-Security-Policy>
      </securityHttpHeaders>
    </httpHeaderSecurityModule>
  </nwebsec>
```

Comment: Thanks, Steve, but per your code still if you are using inline scripts or styles it is still a security issue and can be injectable. To prevent want to use a nonce